# How to change safely storage controller mode from RST to AHCI in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios, ahci, intel-rst

can you please hint me to a solution. I try to change the storage "controller mode" in Windows 10. Currently it is set in my Bios/UEFI to RST mode. I like to change it to AHCI.

1. Is it right that AHCI mode supports the so called "TRIM" feature of SSD and RST does not support that?
2. I tried to change it in Bios to AHCI but it prompted a warning saying that all data in the drive will be erased. How can I then boot to my Windows system?
3. Any solid workaround available to change from RST to AHCI and still be able to boot your existing Windows installation?
4. I read about restarting the pc in safe mode and after that make the switch to AHCI. I would normally do this method but when I read about the "all data will be erased" I thought to ask before doing it.
5. What role is the Intel Rapid Storage feature playing in all of this? Would Intel still work with AHCI?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing from RAID to AHCI and Windows 7 will not boot](https://superuser.com/questions/471523/changing-from-raid-to-ahci-and-windows-7-will-not-boot).  fyi: `Intel RST` is a RAID.  However, I don't actually suggest you change it, since Intel RST supports TRIM.  There is a reason your firmware is configured as Intel RST, but you have not specified enough information, to gleam the reason that might be the case.  I strongly suggest you do not make this change (but it's still a duplicate).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/738722/is-there-a-chance-to-lose-data-if-i-switch-raid-to-ahci?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to answer your second question by saying that your fourth point is valid, since I've just switched a brand new Dell XPS 9310 from RST to AHCI without losing anything (AFAIKT :))
So:

1. Boot into Windows
2. Open a shell as administrator
3. Run `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
4. Reboot, enter BIOS and switch to AHCI
5. Reboot into Windows again
6. Open another shell as administrator
7. Run `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
8. Reboot