# Issue with dual booting windows and ubuntu in acer nitro 5

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bios, windows-registry

I am trying to dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu in new acer nitro 5. However, during installation I was redirected by ubuntu installer to change the storage controller protocol from RST to Advanced Host Controller Interface (AHCI). However, After changing this setting, Windows is unable to boot properly. To resolve it, I need to change some registry in windows OS as per Ubuntu help. However, upon restarting the windows, all the registry changes are reverting back to default values (Ubuntu is still not installed). This is more technical stuff than I have knowledge. Can anyone help me with this registry changes?

[the issue is related to windows, so I tried contacting Microsoft support, but they are reluctant to help me this issue as it is about installing another operating system with this.]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367829/issue-with-dual-booting-windows-and-ubuntu-in-acer-nitro-5#comment2349793_1367829

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1529049/how-to-change-safely-storage-controller-mode-from-rst-to-ahci-in-windows-10?rq=1)

Comment: @ChanganAuto, On askubuntu.com, I was told to post that question here as this is appropriate forum for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to AHCI myself recently.

I followed the answer of LinuxSecurityFreak on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1280141/switch-raid-to-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-10) post and everything worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It did work for me. Thanks for suggestions.